# How to change Live DVD drive without reboot? (SquashFS)

Tags: livecd, dvd

Let's assume a PC has 2 optical drives, of which **one can write DVDs** and the other one is a DVD-ROM drive. I have a live Linux Mint Mate 18.3 Sylvia x86_64 on **a DVD-RW.**  (If anyone is interested: It is a Maxell RiTEKW06 with ×6 recording speed).

I booted Linux Mint with the burner drive because **it can read DVD-RW's faster** (×12 CAV to be specific) than the DVD-ROM drive (×4 CAV only).
Now I need to burn a DVD but I do not wish to restart the PC, just in order to make Linux use the upper drive for SquashFS (live session file system).

I used the example to make it understandable what I mean in a possible real-life situation. In reality, I tested whether Linux can be booted from an external DVD drive, connected via USB. 
Now I need that port, so I wish to swap the live DVD to the internal laptop DVD drive.

#### How do I tell Linux to use a different drive as live drive without rebooting the system?

Comment: Thanks, @RuiFRibeiro. But Isn't this *Linux*? Godfather of all operating systems?

Comment: The true Unix are the *BSDs, not Linux. See FreeBSD. But I digress. If you prepare a setup where you load your / in RAM you might be able to do it. But this is a generic live OS, it was not setup with that in mind. Even if you managed to migrate / to someplace else, it won' t be that easy.